# How to store Pictures folder on another hard drive?

Tags: symbolic-link

I have multiple drives in a desktop computer. I want one of those drives to function as my `/home/username/Pictures` folder. Can this be done?

I thought symbolic links could do this, but I'm not having any success.
The target drive is `/media/Images`. Here's what I tried so far:

[image: terminal screenshot]

All four variations give me the same result, a shortcut *inside* the `/Pictures` folder.

[image: link inside folder]

This isn't what I want. I want the **`/Pictures` folder itself** to be the shortcut. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why it's as simple as deleting the Pictures folder first before linking my good man. Like so:

```
rm -rf ~/Pictures

ln -s /media/Images ~/Pictures
```

Comment: I hope it's something simple like this. I just tried your command and got "rm: cannot remove `/home/tom/Pictures': Is a directory" as an error.

Comment: rm -rf !!!!!!!!

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was getting so frustrated! A quick [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) edit and I'm all set now.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired with the answer of @SomKit. But I stick to more safe method to **not** delete the files

```
mv Pictures/ /media/akpp/data1/screenshots/
ln -s /media/akpp/data1/screenshots/ ~/Pictures
```

I moved target folder to a new location with a new name, then created a link for new folder in the old location